# SQL query with loop

Tags: sql, ms-access, duplicates, foreign-key-relationship

I am having trouble with writing a SQL query in `Access` with foreign keys. There are two tables, 'Customers'(ID, Name, Surname) and 'Orders'(ID, Customer, Date, Volume). ID fields are primary, and `Orders.Customer` is a foreign key linked to `Customers.ID`, so a customer can have many orders or none.

My goal is to do a search on customers based on many criteria, one of which being if customers have at least an order which volume is superior to a certain quantity. I tried joins with `SELECT DISTINCT` but it still gives me duplicate results, plus I had to create an empty order for every customer without orders if the query didn't use the above condition.

Does anyone have an idea about that? Maybe some special instruction on foreign keys or 2 separate queries?

Comment: Do you want your results to be about customers or orders ?

Comment: On customers, I just edited the question thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the information you give, i only can give you hints on what I think you're doing/understanding wrong :

- `SELECT DISTINCT` does select you a unique *record*, not a unique *value*, so if your statement selects all fields (*), distinct won't help you much there.
- My guess is you had to create an empty order for each customer because you used `INNER JOIN`, try `LEFT OUTER JOIN` instead

For example :

```
SELECT DISTINCT Customers.*
FROM Customers
LEFT OUTER JOIN Orders
  ON (Orders.Customer = Customers.id)
WHERE Volume > put_your_value
```

Comment: Yes I did use inner join at first. I think distinct didn't work here because the records from the join table have distinct orders, but I still want to get distinct records from the `Customers` table. These are just example tables, the ones I am working on have about 50 columns each, I didn't know about the `<Table>.*` thing :)